# just trying to sum 2 specific elements of a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

i am a first month java script student and i am just trying to add 2 indexes of a javascript code, this is what i have so far.. i created input boxes for the array variables... any help would be appreciated for a padawan. thank you in advance.

```
function addIndex (){
    var elementz = new Array(3);            
    elementz[0] = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
    elementz[1] = parseFloat(document.getElementById('secondindex').value);
    elementz[2] = parseFloat(document.getElementById('thirdindex').value);          
    var totale = addEnds(elementz);
    document.getElementById('output').value = totale;           
    function addEnds(elementz) {
        sum = elementz[0] + elementz[2];
        return sum;
    }  
}
```

Comment: Your code works as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/t6f434w5/, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Can you elaborate the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move `addEnds` function outside of `addIndex` function

```
function addIndex (){
    var elementz = new Array(3);

    elementz[0] = parseFloat(document.getElementById('input1').value);
    elementz[1] = parseFloat(document.getElementById('secondindex').value);
    elementz[2] = parseFloat(document.getElementById('thirdindex').value);

    var totale = addEnds(elementz);
    document.getElementById('output').value = totale;
}

function addEnds(elementz) {
    sum = elementz[0] + elementz[2];
    return sum;
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hqo10kb8/